# MongoDB C# Update only fields that are not null

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a document e.g.

```
{
    "_id": "ABC",
    "name": "Bob",
    "age": 42
}
```

I have 2 functions that run separate at separate times. Function A updates the name and function B updates the age. Both of these functions call an external rest service which brings back name or age depending on the service.

I have a class that maps to the mongo document

```
public class Person {
    [BsonId]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("age")]
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Function A will populate only the Id and the Name properties of this class whilst function B will populate the Id and Age properties.

How can I update the mongo document by just passing the Person object from function B so that it keeps the existing value of function A?

I know you can do `Builders<Person>.Update.Set(x => x.Age, <new_age>)` but I want my code to be a bit more dynamic so that if I add another field called 'Phone' I can just call a generic method that will update only the fields that have a value and are not null.

Comment: What are the not null fields you update? There are several questions you pose here...

Comment: I want to partial update a document and function B will only have Id and Age set so Name will be null. I am wondering if there is a way to update the document without knowing the Name (without pulling it back from the db first) and without using the .Set methods. So as if you do with the InsertOneAsync method when you just send the entire object.

Comment: Since Id is BsonId you can update without knowing the name. Use upserts and if your schema is variable better use BsonDocument instead of a strongly typed Person object.

Answer (score 2):

Only add the elements you want to update to a new BsonDocument, in order to create your update definition.

```
private static void SetUpdatableElements(BsonDocument bdoc, BsonDocument updateDefintion, HashSet<string>() excluded = null, string parentName = "")
{
    var excluded = excluded ?? new HashSet<string>()
    parentName = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(parentName) ? $"{parentName}." : "";
    foreach (var item in bdoc)
    {
        if (item.Value.IsObjectId || // skip _id                     
            item.Value.IsBsonNull || // skip properties with null values
            excluded.Contains(item.Name)) // skip other properties that should not be updated
        {
            continue;
        }
        if (!item.Value.IsBsonDocument) // to avoid override nested objects)
        {
            updateDefintion = updateDefintion.Add($"{parentName}{item.Name}", item.Value);
            continue;
        }
        // recursively set nested elements to avoid overriding the full object
        SetUpdatableElements(item.Value.ToBsonDocument(), updateDefintion, item.Name);
    }
}
```

The caller:

```
var person = new Person() { Id = "ABC", Name = "bob", Age:42, Phone="123 456 7890"}
var updateDefintion = new BsonDocument();
var bDoc = person.ToBsonDocument();
SetUpdatableElements(person.ToBsonDocument(), updateDefintion, new HashSet<string>(nameof(person.Name)))
collection.UpdateOneAsync<Person>(p => p.Id == person.Id, new BsonDocument("$set", updateDefintion));
```

At the end, your updateDefinition should be something like:

```
{ {
    "$set": {
        "age": 42
        "phone": "123 456 7890"
    }
} }
```